# How to keep certain textures constant size even if camera is zoomed in?

Tags: java, android, game-engine, libgdx

I am using libgdx to builda 2D puzzle type game. The size is bigger than the actual screen size,so we use a pinch zoom function to see smaller parts of the map. The problem is that when i zoom the pause menu also appears bigger.Is there any way that i can make the pause menu appear the same size, even if the camera.zoom is not at default.

Because the way it is now the in game menu zooms with the level. Is there anyway to keep certain sprites constant size throughout the entire game?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply a different camera to the zoomable objects on screen than you use for the non-zoomable objects.  Depending on which Libgdx APIs you're using (scene2d, SpriteBatch, raw OpenGL), the specifics are different, but the general idea is the same.  See https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/31379/how-do-i-make-an-on-screen-hud-in-libgdx for some details.